# What is the accepted way to transfer public-private keypairs over intranet?

Tags: networking, key, rsa, pkcs

I have an embedded system (Netburner 5441x) that consumes public-private RSA keypairs.  I have ported OpenSSL into the system but the processor cannot make keypairs fast enough for the application.  So the next logical step is to have the embedded system, which has Ethernet, get keys from a PC based server.

I've read about half the PKCS#N documents and it looks like it's all about object formats.  Is there an accepted network protocol for transferring public-private keypairs?  Would you just open a secure socket and send the PKCS objects with no other framing?  Use a shared Key Encryption Key, or have the client send a public RSA key for key encryption by the server?

Is there a standard?

Edit 13Jun22 in response to StackOverflow blocking the question:  This question is not asking for **recommendation of a book** etc., but whether a standard exists for a particular unusual use case.  If such a standard existed, that **citation** would answer the question.  Respectfully request removal of the block.

Comment: Instead of RSA you might consider elliptic curve-based cryptography which can generate key pairs much faster than RSA for a given security level.

Comment: Any protocol that requires a lot of RSA key pair generation is not designed well. What do you need this for? How are you using OpenSSL? Are you using it from the command line or from a C/C++ application? Because transporting RSA private keys is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: @PresPolk, I am programming devices for an existing application.  I have no control over the choice of RSA.

Comment: @Maarten, OpenSSL is "ported" into my embedded code, which means cross compiled and linked in.  There is no command line.  Each device I program requires a new public-private key pair - I didn't design the protocols.  The Coldfire processor cannot keep up with RSA key generation while also managing the process, so the keys must be made by a different intranet node and sent over.  I want to follow a standard if one exists for that network communication.  The question is, does that standard exist?

Comment: "Each device I program requires a new public-private key pair" so let the devices generate their own key pair and have them send their public key over a trusted channel? The idea of a private key is to keep it as local as possible. By the way, these kind of questions are more suitable for [security.se].

Comment: @Maarten, I get that I asked you for help, but I can't redesign the system at this point.  I just want to know if a standard exists for this kind of machine-to-machine key transfer.  Maybe something normally used with a key store or HSM.  I don't see anything in PKCS, but that's a lot of docs and I may have missed something.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to Security stack exchange, @Maarten.  I will try there tomorrow.    I did look at Cryptography and that looked more wrong for the question than this general forum.

Comment: I'm moderator at Cryptography, if I had thought it would match there I would have indicated it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Information Security Stack Exchange, there is no accepted answer for this unusual use case.  The best practice seems to be setting up a web service that serves passphrase encoded key files over HTTPS, which implies SSL protection.
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/262533/what-is-the-right-way-to-transfer-public-private-keypairs-over-intranet